# how to open programatically new file in embedded Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to embed Visual Studio Code in an application. Once embedded I would like to ask it from my application to open a new file in a new tab.

I imagine this to be some JavaScript functionality I call on in the browser, but it could also be an HTTP GET/POST on the server side.

My ideal solution would be some JavaScript function I can call in the Firefox Web Development console, and have a new tab with the file opened.

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps thinking about embedding the Monaco Editor (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) into your app. This is what powers up the VS Code and it can (somehow) work in a browser.

The only way I can find to solve your problem is, as you can see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1330 , to do it somehow like that in your JavaScript code:

```
var function-pointed-file-value = # read the data from a local file or using Ajax
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("your-container-div"), {
    theme: 'vs',
    value: function-pointed-file-value
});
```

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/browser-amd-editor/index.html

What am i suggesting is to create a site in your app (I guess we're talking about a web-based solution) which contains a function witch takes the filename from the GET or POST request data and reads the file's content from whatever you want it's location to be (local disk, remote HTTP server), and then loads it into the Monaco editor on that site like my code above shows.

How can be that called as a JavaScript function? Here we run into another problem. The only way i see is window.open("URL-of-the-site-with-monaco-editor", "_blank"), but the result (new window or tab) depends on user preferences. To open it in a new tab, it has to be a separate site. However, if it is intended to be embedded into a web-app (as I understand), isn't it better to use:

```
<a href="URL-of-the-site-with-monaco-editor" target="_blank">Link to editor</a>
```

somewhere in your code?